# How do I plot two animations in a single plot with matplotlib?

Tags: animation, matplotlib, graph

In the following code I have two separate animations and I have plotted them in a two separate subplots. I want both of them to run in a single plot instead of this. I have tried the approach explained below but it is giving me issues as explained below. Please help

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time as t

x = np.linspace(0,5,100)

fig = plt.figure()
p1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
p2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)

def gen1():
    i = 0.5
    while(True):
        yield i
        i += 0.1


def gen2():
    j = 0
    while(True):
        yield j
        j += 1


def run1(c):
    p1.clear()
    p1.set_xlim([0,15])
    p1.set_ylim([0,100])

    y = c*x
    p1.plot(x,y,'b')

def run2(c):
    p2.clear()
    p2.set_xlim([0,15])
    p2.set_ylim([0,100])

    y = c*x
    p2.plot(x,y,'r')

ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,run1,gen1,interval=1)
ani2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,run2,gen2,interval=1)
fig.show()
```

I tried creating a single subplot instead of `p1` and `p2` and have both the plots graphed in that single subplot. That is just plotting one graph and not both of them. As far as I can say it is because one of them is getting cleared right after it is plotted.

How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you do not show the code that is actually producing the problem, it's hard to tell where the problem lies.

But to answer the question of how to animate two lines in the same axes (subplot), we can just get rid of the `clear()` command and update the lines, instead of producing a new plot for every frame (which is more efficient anyways).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x = np.linspace(0,15,100)

fig = plt.figure()
p1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

p1.set_xlim([0,15])
p1.set_ylim([0,100])

# set up empty lines to be updates later on
l1, = p1.plot([],[],'b')
l2, = p1.plot([],[],'r')

def gen1():
    i = 0.5
    while(True):
        yield i
        i += 0.1

def gen2():
    j = 0
    while(True):
        yield j
        j += 1

def run1(c):
    y = c*x
    l1.set_data(x,y)

def run2(c):
    y = c*x
    l2.set_data(x,y)

ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,run1,gen1,interval=1)
ani2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,run2,gen2,interval=1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is working. To make sure that I post future questions properly, could you please clarify what you mean by I have not provided the code that is actually producing the problem? I posted the entire program here. What more should I have added?

Comment: Sure. The code you post here is working fine. It has two subplots and both are updated as expected. However you are asking about a problem that occurs when using a different code, namely *"creating a single subplot instead of p1 and p2"*. But the code that creates this single subplot remains unknown - thus it's hard to say what's wrong in that case.