# Python function animation for two graphes (displayed after each other)

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, animation

I have two data sets `y1 = vol1` and `y2 = vol2` for the same `x` range (0 to 5000 in steps of 10). I would like to use function animation in order to first animate `y1` and after that animate `y2` while the graph of `y1` remains.
This is what I got from combing several examples (incl. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574024/how-do-i-plot-two-animations-in-a-single-plot-with-matplotlib)):

```
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


x = range(0, 5000, 10)
y1 = vol1
y2 = vol2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 5000)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1000)

l1, = plt.plot([],[],'b-')
l2, = plt.plot([],[],'r-')

def init1():
    return l1,
def init2():
    return l2,

def animate1(i):
    l1.set_data(x[:i],y1[:i])
    return l1,
def animate2(i):
    l2.set_data(x[:i-500],y2[:i-500])
    return l2,

def gen1():
    i = 0
    while(i<500):
        yield i
        i += 1
def gen2():
    j = 500
    while(j<1000):
        yield j
        j += 1

ani1 = FuncAnimation(fig, animate1, gen1, interval=1, save_count=len(x),
                    init_func=init1, blit=True,
                    repeat=False) 
ani2 = FuncAnimation(fig, animate2, gen2, interval=1, save_count=len(x),
                        init_func=init2, blit=True,
                        repeat=False)
    # ani.save('ani.mp4')
plt.show()
```

My idea was to make two 'counters' `gen1` and`gen2` but since I have the same x values for both data sets, I tried to compensate that in the `animate2` function. But this doesn't work..
Obviously, I'm quite new to python and I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do just one animation, keeping track of the frame with respect to the line length:

```
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, FFMpegWriter

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)
k = 0

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, x.max())
ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)

l1, = plt.plot([],[],'b-')
l2, = plt.plot([],[],'r-')

def animate1(i):
    global k
    
    if k > 2 * len(x):
        # reset if "repeat=True"
        k = 0
    
    if k <= len(x):
        l1.set_data(x[:k],y1[:k])
    else:
        l2.set_data(x[:k - len(x)],y2[:k - len(x)])
    k += 1

ani1 = FuncAnimation(fig, animate1, frames=2*len(x), interval=1, repeat=True)
writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=10)
ani1.save("test.mp4", writer=writer)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure it works for me. How can I save this animation? If I try `ani1.save('animation.pm4')` I get an error: ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Comment: Sorry there is a typo, I tried `ani1.save('animation.mp4')`

Comment: I have modified the answer to save the animation. You have to use an appropriate `writer` object. I've tried it locally and I didn't get any errors.